# Java (openjdk version "1.8.0_151", linux) millions of records in memory. Often adding and requesting sorted data

Tags: java, sorting, types

Every record have id, price and quantity. When new record is added if id already exist, new record replace old one, id is unique in data set. Very often I need to get sorted data(by price). Like top 100 or 25-50 position in data set. Good thing is that every time I need sorted data is from starting of data set. (I have used Comparable compareTo(Object o) when I could).

I have tried storing data into:

1. ArrayList replacing element when id is same or add element on the end. Sorting it when data is needed. Too slow.
2. ArrayDeque removing old element if exist and adding new element. Sorting it when data is needed. Too slow.
3. HashMap helps with unique id and replacing existing ones. When sorting  I took values from HashMap and sort them as ArrayList. Faster but still not enough.
4. TreeMap helps with unique id but can't sort it then by key. Sorting values as ArrayList. Same as HashMap.
5. SortedSet(TreeSet)  removing old element if exist and adding new element. Get sorted elements using iterator. Fastest by now but still not enough.

   I have checked Java Collections – Performance (Time Complexity) on operation [here](http://infotechgems.blogspot.rs/2011/11/java-collections-performance-time.html) and [here](http://web.archive.org/web/20120105103844/http://www.coderfriendly.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/05/java_collections_v2.pdf).

If someone have any suggestion what data type / sorting to use or how to make this as fast as possible.

I have some time required for this for example there is 100 millions of records updated(add/replace) and sorted on request. Without using any benchmark software on octa/quad core(eight thread CPU) on 4Ghz should be around 2,3 minutes. Keep in mind that as number of records grown time for add/replace and sort are higher.

Comment: Have you considered using a separate database tier for your data? Databases have structures optimized for just the kind of queries you're describing. Internally, databases often use B-tree datastructures to sort the data, whether they're in-memory databases or not.

Comment: Can you quantify the actual number of records and what you would deem to be "fast enough?"

Comment: At the moment using any type of database is not an option. For example  there could be around 100 millions of records updated(add/replace). Without using any benchmark software on octa/quad core(eight tread CPU) on 4Ghz should be around 2,3 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

*As [suggested by László van den Hoek](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49639361/java-openjdk-version-1-8-0-151-linux-millions-of-records-in-memory-often-a#comment86286657_49639361), you should consider actually storing your data in a database, which can handle large amounts of data, and can index the data for faster sorted lookups.*

However, for you home-grown in-memory data "store", you should maintain both a `HashMap` for lookup by `id`, and a `TreeSet` for sorted access.

You didn't specify what sorting you were using, so below I'll assume you meant to sort by `price`.

A `TreeSet` requires elements to be unique, so to sort by `price` you also need to sort secondarily by `id`, to make the sort key unique. *Bonus side-effect:* Consistent sorting of records with same `price`.

First, we fully define your `Record` class:

```
class Record implements Comparable<Record> {
    private int id;
    private double price;
    private int quantity;

    public Record(int id, double price, int quantity) {
        this.id = id;
        this.price = price;
        this.quantity = quantity;
    }

    public Record(double price, int id) {
        this.id = id;
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public double getPrice() {
        return this.price;
    }

    public int getQuantity() {
        return this.quantity;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Record that) {
        int cmp = Double.compare(this.price, that.price);
        if (cmp == 0)
            cmp = Integer.compare(this.id, that.id);
        return cmp;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (! (obj instanceof Record))
            return false;
        Record that = (Record) obj;
        return (this.id == that.id);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return this.id;
    }
}
```

The alternate constructor is a convenience helper for the `DataStore` below.

The `equals` and `hashCode` methods are not needed by the `DataStore` logic, but it's always a good idea to implement them, if equality is well-defined.

Now we implement the `DataStore` class that encapsulates the logic of having both a `HashMap` and a `TreeSet`:

```
class DataStore {
    private Map<Integer, Record> recordsById = new HashMap<>();
    private TreeSet<Record> recordsByPrice = new TreeSet<>();

    public Optional<Record> addOrReplace(Record newRecord) {
        Record oldRecord = this.recordsById.put(newRecord.getId(), newRecord);
        if (oldRecord != null)
            this.recordsByPrice.remove(oldRecord);
        this.recordsByPrice.add(newRecord);
        return Optional.ofNullable(oldRecord);
    }

    public Optional<Record> remove(int id) {
        Record oldRecord = this.recordsById.remove(id);
        if (oldRecord != null)
            this.recordsByPrice.remove(oldRecord);
        return Optional.ofNullable(oldRecord);
    }

    public Optional<Record> getById(int id) {
        return Optional.ofNullable(this.recordsById.get(id));
    }

    public NavigableSet<Record> getByPrice(double price) {
        return this.recordsByPrice.subSet(new Record(price, Integer.MIN_VALUE), true,
                                          new Record(price, Integer.MAX_VALUE), true);
    }

    public NavigableSet<Record> getByPriceRange(double fromPriceInclusive, double toPriceExclusive) {
        return this.recordsByPrice.subSet(new Record(fromPriceInclusive, Integer.MIN_VALUE), true,
                                          new Record(toPriceExclusive, Integer.MIN_VALUE), false);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is nice but I need it as fast as possible. Having HashMap and TreeSet  is time consuming. For  example in addOrReplace we have HashMap put method (O(1)) + TreeSet remove optional(O(log n)) + TreeSet add method (O(log n)). That means there is O(1) + O(log n)(Maybe) + O(log n). Witch is slower then having almost any single Collection usage. When we have millions of record operation comes expensive. For example in TreeSet faster way is to call remove(Object o), add(Object o) then check with contain(Object o), optional remove(Object o) and add(Object o).

Comment: @exp2Tapavicki I just created 1 million random records, where about 50000 of them had same `id`, and added them to `DataStore`. Run time: 1.2 seconds. Is that "time consuming"? All relative, I guess. Since you need the data sorted, your overall performance will be _O(n log n)_, which is performance of this code too. Nothing you can do about that, so what is "good enough"? You sure you don't have an unobtainable goal?

Comment: Sorry I added some information in comment on question. 
For example there could be around 100 millions of records updated(add/replace) and sorted. Without using any benchmark software on octa/quad core(eight tread CPU) on 4Ghz should be around 2,3 minutes. Keep in mind that as number of records grown time for add/replace and sort are higher.

Comment: @exp2Tapavicki You have a 100 million *new* records per day? Or did you mean that your "database" is now 100 million records, with N number of new records per day, and that you need continual access to the data, in the form of lookup by id and querying top X? Because it sound more and more like you don't want an in-memory solution (you'll eventually run out), but need a database solution, like we've already suggested to you.

Comment: It doesn't have any database. Database communication will only increase time. Code should be as simple as possible. There is only 100 millions of record. After that is finished that's it. No more operation.